# MYSQL QUERY select from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have table inbox and table outbox.
I want order by by date.
tabel: inbox
[image]

tabel: outbox
[image]

AND I want the QUERY and the result like this
[image]
thanks

Comment: `Give a man a fish, he will eat for a day. Teach a man how to fish, he will eat for a lifetime`.. So I am giving you a fishing rod : `UNION` + `ORDER BY`.

Comment: ... and I want to triple my salary :) Well, welcome to StackOverflow. You may start with this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show what you have tried, how it works, what issues you have. SO is not a sitie for solving your homework *instead* of you!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `union all` and `order by`:

```
select SenderNumber as Number, TextDecoded, date
from inbox
union all
select DestinationNumber, TextDecoded, date
from outbox
order by date;
```

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your query and is running but please check my question update